# How do I aggregate from multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp, aggregate-functions

I have the below table:

```
Person_ID   | Timestamp           | Action
1           | 01-01-2020 00:01:00 | LOGGED ON
1           | 01-01-2020 00:02:00 | ON BREAK
1           | 01-01-2020 00:02:30 | OFF BREAK
1           | 01-01-2020 00:04:00 | LOGGED OFF
1           | 01-01-2020 00:04:30 | LOGGED ON
1           | 01-01-2020 00:05:30 | ON BREAK
1           | 01-01-2020 00:06:00 | OFF BREAK
1           | 01-01-2020 00:08:00 | LOGGED OFF
2           | 01-02-2020 00:04:00 | LOGGED ON
2           | 01-02-2020 00:10:00 | LOGGED OFF
```

My goal is to write an SQL view to get the below result:

```
Person_ID   | LoggedInTime_hours | OnBreakTime_hours
1           | 6.5                | 1 
2           | 6                  | 0
```

For each Person_ID, calculate the difference in hours between each pair of occurrences of LOGGED IN/LOGGED OUT and ON BREAK/OFF BREAK respectively.

Thanks a lot for your expertise and help.

Comment: I think that you misplaced the hour part with minute part in your timestamps, i.e. `01-01-2020 00:01:00` should be `01-01-2020 01:00:00`, otherwise; the expected results should be in minutes not hours.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all LoggedInTime_hours for PERSON_ID = 1 should be 5.5 hours not 6.5 hours.

Let us assume the table name is **TEST**.

Database : MySQL

```
SELECT
PERSON_ID,
IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN PREV_ACTIVE_IND - ACTIVE_IND > 0 THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, PREV_TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP)/3600 END),0) LoggedInTime_hours,
IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN PREV_ACTIVE_IND - ACTIVE_IND = 0 THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, PREV_TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP)/3600 END),0) OnBreakTime_hours
FROM
(SELECT
PERSON_ID,
PREV_ACTION,
ACTION,
CASE WHEN PREV_ACTION = 'LOGGED OFF' THEN 1 
WHEN PREV_ACTION LIKE '%BREAK' THEN 2 
WHEN PREV_ACTION IS NULL THEN NULL 
ELSE 3 
END AS PREV_ACTIVE_IND,
CASE WHEN ACTION = 'LOGGED OFF' THEN 1
WHEN ACTION LIKE '%BREAK' THEN 2
WHEN ACTION IS NULL THEN NULL
ELSE 3 
END AS ACTIVE_IND,
PREV_TIMESTAMP,
TIMESTAMP
FROM
(SELECT PERSON_ID,
TIMESTAMP,
LAG(TIMESTAMP,1) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID) PREV_TIMESTAMP,
LAG(ACTION,1) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID) PREV_ACTION,
ACTION
FROM TEST) T) T2
GROUP BY PERSON_ID
```

Hope this query will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query using `MySQL v8.0`:

```
With CTE As
(
  Select Person_ID, Action_,
  TIME_TO_SEC(
    TIMEDIFF(
              Lead(Timestamp_) Over (Partition By Person_ID 
              Order By Case When Action_ In 'LOGGED ON','LOGGED OFF')
              Then 1 Else 2 End,Timestamp_), Timestamp_
             ))/3600 As DIFF
  From MyData 
)

Select Person_ID, 
Sum(Case When Action_='LOGGED ON' Then DIFF Else 0 End) As LoggedInTime_hours,
Sum(Case When Action_='ON BREAK' Then DIFF Else 0 End) As OnBreakTime_hours 
From CTE
Group By Person_ID
```

See a demo from ***[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nhsL9k7XQXbSvoi27U9F2e/2)***.

The `Lead()` function will find the next action date related to the current action i.e. (Logged In -> Logged Off), the actions are ordered according to their types; `('LOGGED ON','LOGGED OFF')` ordered with 1, and `('ON BREAK','OFF BREAK')` ordered with 2, then ordered by `Timestamp` of the action. Doing so, will ensure that each `'LOGGED ON'` is followed by it's `'LOGGED OFF'` action, and each `'ON BREAK'` is followed by it's `'OFF BREAK'` action.

Using `TIMEDIFF` we can find the difference between the actions times for each pair of actions `('LOGGED ON','LOGGED OFF')`, `('ON BREAK','OFF BREAK')`. Then the sum of these differences will be `LoggedInTime_hours` for logged in actions, and `OnBreakTime_hours`  for on break actions.

The `TIME_TO_SEC()/3600` is used to convert time differences to hours.